# command to add multiple "secondary groups" for a user in Solaris

Tags: unix, solaris, solaris-10

I am trying to add 2 secondary groups for a user is Solaris system, but not able to do so. It only adds 1 secondary groups. I've done enough R&D, not sure what to do.

Below command I am using :-

```
sudo usermod -g Primarygrp -G Secondarygrp1,Secondarygrp2 TJ252020
```

when I verify whether groups has been added or not, I use below command :-

```
id -Gn TJ252020
```

o/p I am getting- > Primarygrp Secondarygrp1

o/p I want -> Primarygrp Secondarygrp1 Secondarygrp2

Comment: Did you read the `-G` portion of `man usermod`?

Comment: Yes I did, but I am not sure how to use it. If you've any link please share

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on unix.stackexchange.com instead.